# Simply inserting a column with a date

Tags: oracle

Trying to insert a column with a date

```
INSERT 
INTO o_employees (date)
VALUES (DATE (to_date('20030203', 'yyyymmdd'))
```

Is giving me missing select keyword??

Comment: You related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046650/simply-creating-a-table-in-oracle-sql? Have you read anything about [the INSERT syntax](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php)?

Comment: Don't know if this is the answer or not, but make sure to close your last )

Comment: Im sure my last ) is closed and @Ben no I'm not

Comment: Also, the word `date` can't be used for a column name because it's a reserved word. You can double-quote it to specify it's a column, but it's better to just name it something different.

Comment: As a general advice: don't ignore the ORA-#### error codes. They're incredibly useful. For instance, you always get help when you Google for them.

Comment: Okay sorry about using date and the column name so I changed my code to : INSERT 
INTO o_employees ("Date")
VALUES (DATE (to_date('20030203', 'yyyymmdd'))) and it's still saying missing expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your post, you're missing the closing parenthesis. Here's an example, and please read the points below:

```
INSERT INTO o_employees ("date")
  VALUES (DATE '2003-02-03')
```

1. The word `DATE` (including lowercase `date`) is reserved. If your column is named `DATE` it has to be surrounded by double quotes. Best solution, however, is to name the column something else. I *strongly* suggest you do this.
2. Use the ANSI literal for literal dates: `DATE '2003-02-03'`. Your `to_date('20030203', 'yyyymmdd')` all alone (without the `DATE` prefix) would have worked, but always try to favor the ANSI way.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to use DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE instead of the ANSI literal,, please dont give me negative score :( I'm new

Comment: No worries @Applesauce - I wouldn't vote down a newbie unless they continually ignored requests to clarify a question. I'd rather help you frame your question properly because that's a skill every IT person should develop. Did my answer work for you, or is it the current date you want to insert?

Comment: ^^ look at my last comment

Comment: @Applesauce - please paste your *exact* insert statement as a new comment and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: INSERT INTO o_employees (Termination Time)
  VALUES (DATE '2003-02-03')

Comment: Your column name has a space in it @Apple, you need to use the _exact_ same name as you used to create the table.

Comment: It's because of the space in `Termination Time`. What is the name of the column you're trying to update? If it's `TerminationTime` just lose the space. If you really do have a space in the column name you'll need the double quotes again: `INSERT INTO o_employees ("Termination Time") VALUES (DATE '2003-02-03')`. But I'd recommend not using column names with spaces - as you're probably starting to realize by now, they cause no end of grief :)

Comment: @ Ed Gibbs I'm sorry for not clarifying,, this column has not been created yet. So I need to create the column and add the date. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Applesauce - I'll help you create the column, but after that you should find a basic reference for Oracle. It'll be faster for you than posting the questions here. OK, if the `o_employees` table doesn't already exist then do this: `CREATE TABLE o_employees (TerminationTime DATE)`. If the table already exists and you just need to add the column do this: `ALTER TABLE o_employees ADD TerminationTime DATE`.

Comment: Okay so after I added the column, how do I insert the actual date?

Comment: OK, one more answer, but I'm about to call it a day so I won't be available any more this evening. To insert 2/3/2003 do this: `INSERT INTO o_employees (TerminationTime) VALUES (DATE '2003-02-03')`. To insert the current date and time do this: `INSERT INTO o_employees (TerminationTime) VALUES (SYSDATE)`.

Comment: BZ for the ANSI date syntax.